# Identifying if an LP is unsolvable or solvable and finding lower bound without Simplex?

Tags: linear-programming

I have no idea how to solve the following problem without using Simplex. Below is the LP

$\min -47x_1 + 13x_2 + 22x_3 $ subject to

$-4x_1 + x_2 - 17x_3 \geq 2$

$-x_1 + x_2 + 39x_3 \geq 1$

$x_1, x_2, x_3 >0$

I have the dual written down as:

$\max 2u_1 + u_2$ such that

$-4u_1 - u_2 \leq -47$

$u_1 + u_2 \leq 13$

$-17u_1 + 39u_2 \leq 22$

$u_1, u_2, u_3 \geq 0$

And I'm not really sure where to go from here. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Minor note: your dual LP should only have two variables $u_1$ and $u_2$, since the primal LP only has two constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what other techniques that *aren't* the simplex method you're fine with using, but in this case, since the dual LP only has two variables, you could solve it by graphing.

Once you have a dual solution, you can use complementary slackness to get a primal solution:

- Whenever a dual variable is nonzero, the corresponding primal constraint is tight (satisfied with equality), giving you an equation that $x_1, x_2, x_3$ must satisfy.
- whenever a dual constraint is *not* tight, the corresponding primal variable must be $0$, letting you get rid of a variable.

Once you have a primal solution and a dual solution, it should be straightforward to confirm you've done everything right by checking that the objective values are the same.

Comment: Thanks. I tested this with Phase I even though the question explicitly states not to. What would a graph look like for an infeasible LP?

Comment: At some point as you're drawing the constraints, you'll see that the next constraint tells you that all solutions are on one side of a line, but the feasible region formed by the previous constraints is entirely on the other side of that line. For example, if you have $x \ge 1$ and $y \ge 1$, these form an open cone starting from $(1,1)$. If you add the constraint $x+y\le 1$, that constraint describes a region entirely disjoint from the cone.